# my scene is rendered upside down

Tags: android, graphics, opengl-es, libgdx

I have a problem with the rendering of a scene that I'm developing for a small project. It appears that my scene is actually rendered upside down and I can't figure out why.

[image]

You can see that the option button is actually rendered with the right orientation, while the rest of the scene is not. I tried to simply invert the y coordinate of the position returned by the shader but it messes up with the movement of the brown cube.

This is the shader that I wrote:

```
#ifndef GL_ES
#version 330
#endif

uniform mat4 u_projectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 u_viewMatrix;

uniform vec3 u_scale;
uniform mat4 u_rotation;
uniform vec3 u_position;
uniform vec2 u_textureScale;
uniform vec2 u_textureOffset;

attribute vec4 a_position;
attribute vec3 a_normal;
attribute vec2 a_texCoord0;

varying vec4 v_position;
varying vec4 v_normal;
varying vec2 v_texCoords;

void main()
{
// Not sure why some vec4's need 0 or 1, since it's the w-coordinate (shouldn't this      always be 1 prior to applying the projection matrix?).
v_position = vec4(u_position, 0) + (u_rotation * (a_position * vec4(u_scale, 1)));
v_normal = normalize(u_rotation * vec4(a_normal, 0));
v_texCoords = (a_texCoord0 * u_textureScale) + u_textureOffset;

gl_Position = u_projectionMatrix * u_viewMatrix * v_position;
//gl_Position.y = -gl_Position.y;
}
```

This is the code for the camera:

```
public void create() {
...

_camera = new PerspectiveCamera(67, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),Gdx.graphics.getHeight());

_camera.translate(0, -10, 20);
_camera.lookAt(new Vector3(0,0,0));
_camera.near = 0.1f;

...
}
```

Can anybody help?

EDIT: Changing the y coordinate of the up vector fixes the orientation problem with the scene but makes the button disappear, like it's not rendered. Here's the code that I use to draw the options button:

```
public void create() {
    //camera code and other initialization stuff...

    // Create new stage for the ui.
    toggleOptions = new Stage();


    // Add a menu button.
    Table toggleBtn = new Table(skin);
    toggleOptions.addActor(toggleBtn);

    initUI();

    ...
    }

    private void initUI(){

    final TextButton toggleMenuButton = new TextButton("Options", skin);

    menuWidgets.put("toggleMenu", toggleMenuButton);
    toggleMenuButton.addListener(new ChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
            // Toggle the menu.
            showMenu = !showMenu;
        }
    });

    // Set up button so that is appears in the bottom center of the screen (with some padding).
    toggleMenuButton.setPosition((Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2.0f) - toggleMenuButton.getWidth() / 2.0f, padY);


    toggleMenuButton.setWidth(toggleMenuButton.getWidth() + padX);

    // Add the toggle button.
    toggleOptions.addActor(toggleMenuButton);
}

    public void render() {
    ...
    toggleOptions.act();
    toggleOptions.draw();
    ...
    }
```

EDIT 2: Ok, the issue was that the button was rendered behind the plane and the cube because the draw call was misplaced (it was supposed to be the last call, but instead I called it before the plane draw and cube draw). Thanks for the help, everyone.

Comment: This: _camera.translate(0, -10, 20); looks suspect. What if you put 10 instead of -10?

Comment: Where and how do you set your view matrix? There should a call to Matrix.setLookAtM somewhere in your code. Is the up vector correct?

Comment: @Tobor mmm.. it fixes the orientation of the scene, but the textbutton disappears.

Comment: @NigelK it's set with this line in the render function: `shader.setUniformMatrix("u_viewMatrix", _camera.view);`

Comment: Ok, I also tried to change the y coordinate of the up vector to -y and I again get the scene in the right orientation, but the button just disappears. I'll keep looking into it, but if anybody has an idea it would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

_camera.setOrientation(180.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)

Comment: the camera object doesn't have a setOrientation method

Comment: can you please show (+x, +y and +z axes) on the picture? You can find their directions by translating the box in the scene.

Comment: And in such cases, using a texture with a text or numbers would be useful, so we can understand the direction of the object. This texture does not give any idea about the rotation of the object.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have enough reputation to write a comment under your question, that's why I will write it here, under my answer. As you mention that the issue was the placement of the button; I think that the very first comment of Tobor is the correct answer of your original question, isn't it?